# Android library zip

Tags: java, android, zip

Can someone tell me if there is a Java library for reading/writing zip files which is compatible with Android?

If looked at truezip but it seems not to work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the [`ZipFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class in the API (and the related ones listed there, namely [`ZipOutputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) for creating zip files).

Comment: I recommend you do not use this standard lib. It does not support Unicode zip entry file names!